# How to Mapping JSON data from API Strapi

Tags: arrays, reactjs, api, axios, strapi

hello I'm trying to fetch data from api strapi and display it in reactjs frontend, I'm using axios library,

this 'url' data i want to fetch but always getting response undefined or "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')", see on image

[image json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWWRZ.png)

this is the code I use to get data :

```
componentDidMount() {

    const url = "http://localhost:1337/videos"

    axios.get(url)
        .then(data_video => {
            console.log(data_video.data.video.url);
            this.setState({
                // data: data_video.data
            })
        })
}
```

Comment: Are you using strapi V4 or V3?

Comment: i use strapi V 3.1.0

Comment: You have the roles of public set correctly yes?

Comment: Yes, I check "count", "find", "find one"

Comment: Please  console.log(data_video.data) and post the answer

Comment: I already posted in the answer

Comment: Check my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your state is being set before the api call has finished.

You need a async componentDidMount

```
async componentDidMount() {

    const url = "http://localhost:1337/videos"

    await axios.get(url)
        .then(data_video => {
            console.log(data_video.data.video[0].url);
            this.setState({
                data: data_video.data.video[0].url
            })
        })
}
```

Comment: I try and the response "Video.js:19 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')"

Comment: Sorry forgot the video was an array updated my setState

Comment: i have tried this :  console.log(data_api.data[0].video[0].url);

and it works it's just that the data shown is only 1 and not all of them

Comment: @HeriIrawan Yeah that set state will only work for 1 video. If you have more you leave the state as data: data_video.data.video and then you will map this to get all the videos :)